# Apache-Beam: Wordcount example running in Terminal but build errors in Eclipse

Tags: apache-beam

I imported the Wordcount example to Eclipse and I get the following Build Errors for package `org.apache.beam.examples.complete.game`:

```
Cannot infer type arguments for WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<> LeaderBoard.java    /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 169    Java Problem
Cannot infer type arguments for WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<> LeaderBoard.java    /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 172    Java Problem
Cannot infer type arguments for WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<> LeaderBoard.java    /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 188    Java Problem
Cannot infer type arguments for WriteWindowedToBigQuery.FieldInfo<> GameStats.java  /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 189    Java Problem
Cannot infer type arguments for WriteWindowedToBigQuery.FieldInfo<> GameStats.java  /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 192    Java Problem
Cannot infer type arguments for WriteWindowedToBigQuery.FieldInfo<> GameStats.java  /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 195    Java Problem
Cannot infer type arguments for WriteWindowedToBigQuery.FieldInfo<> GameStats.java  /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 203    Java Problem
Cannot infer type arguments for WriteWindowedToBigQuery.FieldInfo<> GameStats.java  /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 218    Java Problem
Cannot infer type arguments for WriteWindowedToBigQuery.FieldInfo<> GameStats.java  /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 225    Java Problem
Cannot infer type arguments for WriteWindowedToBigQuery.FieldInfo<> LeaderBoard.java    /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 137    Java Problem
Cannot infer type arguments for WriteWindowedToBigQuery.FieldInfo<> LeaderBoard.java    /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 140    Java Problem
Cannot infer type arguments for WriteWindowedToBigQuery.FieldInfo<> LeaderBoard.java    /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 143    Java Problem
Cannot infer type arguments for WriteWindowedToBigQuery.FieldInfo<> LeaderBoard.java    /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 151    Java Problem
Cannot infer type arguments for WriteWindowedToBigQuery.FieldInfo<> LeaderBoard.java    /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 155    Java Problem
Cannot infer type arguments for WriteWindowedToBigQuery.FieldInfo<> StatefulTeamScore.java  /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 102    Java Problem
Cannot infer type arguments for WriteWindowedToBigQuery.FieldInfo<> StatefulTeamScore.java  /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 105    Java Problem
Cannot infer type arguments for WriteWindowedToBigQuery.FieldInfo<> StatefulTeamScore.java  /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 108    Java Problem
The method put(String, WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<Double>) in the type Map<String,WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<Double>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, new WriteWindowedToBigQuery.FieldInfo<>("FLOAT", (<no type> c, <no type> w) -> c.element()))   GameStats.java  /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 224    Java Problem
The method put(String, WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<Double>) in the type Map<String,WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<Double>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, new WriteWindowedToBigQuery.FieldInfo<>("STRING", (<no type> c, <no type> w) -> {
  IntervalWindow window = (IntervalWindow) w;
  return GameConstants.DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.print(window.start());
})) GameStats.java  /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 216    Java Problem
The method put(String, WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<KV<String,Integer>>) in the type Map<String,WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<KV<String,Integer>>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, new WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<>("INTEGER", (<no type> c, <no type> w) -> c.element().getValue()))  LeaderBoard.java    /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 170    Java Problem
The method put(String, WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<KV<String,Integer>>) in the type Map<String,WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<KV<String,Integer>>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, new WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<>("STRING", (<no type> c, <no type> w) -> c.element().getKey())) LeaderBoard.java    /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 168    Java Problem
The method put(String, WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<KV<String,Integer>>) in the type Map<String,WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<KV<String,Integer>>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, new WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<>("STRING", (<no type> c, <no type> w) -> GameConstants.DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.print(Instant.now())))   LeaderBoard.java    /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 186    Java Problem
The method put(String, WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<KV<String,Integer>>) in the type Map<String,WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<KV<String,Integer>>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, new WriteWindowedToBigQuery.FieldInfo<>("INTEGER", (<no type> c, <no type> w) -> c.element().getValue()))  GameStats.java  /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 190    Java Problem
The method put(String, WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<KV<String,Integer>>) in the type Map<String,WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<KV<String,Integer>>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, new WriteWindowedToBigQuery.FieldInfo<>("INTEGER", (<no type> c, <no type> w) -> c.element().getValue()))  LeaderBoard.java    /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 138    Java Problem
The method put(String, WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<KV<String,Integer>>) in the type Map<String,WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<KV<String,Integer>>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, new WriteWindowedToBigQuery.FieldInfo<>("INTEGER", (<no type> c, <no type> w) -> c.element().getValue()))  StatefulTeamScore.java  /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 103    Java Problem
The method put(String, WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<KV<String,Integer>>) in the type Map<String,WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<KV<String,Integer>>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, new WriteWindowedToBigQuery.FieldInfo<>("STRING", (<no type> c, <no type> w) -> {
  IntervalWindow window = (IntervalWindow) w;
  return GameConstants.DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.print(window.start());
})) GameStats.java  /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 193    Java Problem
The method put(String, WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<KV<String,Integer>>) in the type Map<String,WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<KV<String,Integer>>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, new WriteWindowedToBigQuery.FieldInfo<>("STRING", (<no type> c, <no type> w) -> {
  IntervalWindow window = (IntervalWindow) w;
  return GameConstants.DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.print(window.start());
})) LeaderBoard.java    /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 141    Java Problem
The method put(String, WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<KV<String,Integer>>) in the type Map<String,WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<KV<String,Integer>>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, new WriteWindowedToBigQuery.FieldInfo<>("STRING", (<no type> c, <no type> w) -> c.element().getKey())) GameStats.java  /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 188    Java Problem
The method put(String, WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<KV<String,Integer>>) in the type Map<String,WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<KV<String,Integer>>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, new WriteWindowedToBigQuery.FieldInfo<>("STRING", (<no type> c, <no type> w) -> c.element().getKey())) LeaderBoard.java    /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 136    Java Problem
The method put(String, WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<KV<String,Integer>>) in the type Map<String,WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<KV<String,Integer>>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, new WriteWindowedToBigQuery.FieldInfo<>("STRING", (<no type> c, <no type> w) -> c.element().getKey())) StatefulTeamScore.java  /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 101    Java Problem
The method put(String, WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<KV<String,Integer>>) in the type Map<String,WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<KV<String,Integer>>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, new WriteWindowedToBigQuery.FieldInfo<>("STRING", (<no type> c, <no type> w) -> c.pane().getTiming().toString()))  LeaderBoard.java    /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 153    Java Problem
The method put(String, WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<KV<String,Integer>>) in the type Map<String,WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<KV<String,Integer>>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, new WriteWindowedToBigQuery.FieldInfo<>("STRING", (<no type> c, <no type> w) -> GameConstants.DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.print(Instant.now())))   GameStats.java  /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 201    Java Problem
The method put(String, WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<KV<String,Integer>>) in the type Map<String,WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<KV<String,Integer>>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, new WriteWindowedToBigQuery.FieldInfo<>("STRING", (<no type> c, <no type> w) -> GameConstants.DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.print(Instant.now())))   LeaderBoard.java    /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 149    Java Problem
The method put(String, WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<KV<String,Integer>>) in the type Map<String,WriteToBigQuery.FieldInfo<KV<String,Integer>>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, new WriteWindowedToBigQuery.FieldInfo<>("STRING", (<no type> c, <no type> w) -> GameConstants.DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.print(Instant.now())))   StatefulTeamScore.java  /word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game   line 106    Java Problem
```

Comment: It seems like perhaps your build environment is not configured properly. Can you provide more details about how you imported the code, and the steps you are using to build? Also, the versions of the Beam SDK and Eclipse and Java compilers.

Comment: FYI, there are instructions on using Apache Beam in Eclipse here: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-eclipse